# I can't make this program with do-while variable, just with for variable

Tags: java, string, character

I used for variable in program, but i can't how to make this program with do-while variable. (Remark:I maded this in NetBeans, and i am hungary. I used hungarian text in program. Sorry.)

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package karakterkeresés.fr;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Apa---2016
 */
public class KarakterkeresésFr {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner beolv;
beolv=new Scanner(System.in);
int y=0;
String x;
System.out.print("Megadott szó:");
x=beolv.nextLine();
for(int cv=0;cv<x.length();cv++){
if(x.charAt(cv)=='a'){y++;}
else{}
}
if(y>0){System.out.println("A megadott szóban megtatlálható az 'a' karakter.");}
else{System.out.println("A megadott szóban nem megtatlálható az 'a' karakter.");}
System.out.println("A szóban "+y+" 'a' betű található.");
}
}
```

This is working.
But this isn't.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package karakterkeresés.dw;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Apa---2016
 */
public class KarakterkeresésDw {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner beolv;
beolv=new Scanner(System.in);
int y=0;
int z=0;
String x;
String Sg;
System.out.print("Megadott szó:");
x=beolv.nextLine();
do{
if(x.charAt(0+1)=='a'){z++;}
else{}
y++;
}
while(y<=x.length());
if(z>0){System.out.println("A megadott szóban megtalálható az 'a' betű.");}
else{System.out.println("A megadott szóban nem található meg az 'a' betű.");}
System.out.println("A megadott szóban "+z+" 'a' betű található.");
}
}
```

How to make this programs with do-while variable?

Comment: you might as well omit the else statement within the do block since it is not doing anything....

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code, which alone might answer/shed light on your problem.

Comment: please edit your title and question because do-while is a loop not a variable same with for loop and clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

maybe you mean

```
if(x.charAt(y)=='a')
{
  z++;
}
```

Comment: also in your while don't add '=' on your test condition because if you compare it in your for loop it doesn't have '=' character if you think my answer is right you can accept my answer my ticking check this could also cause an error at the charAt() method

Comment: Okay. Tomorrow writing the test in programs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check character at each index using `charAt(y)` and also you don't need unnecessary `else` condition (which doesn't do anything)

```
 do {
    if (x.charAt(y) == 'a') {
        z++;
    } 
    y++;            
  } while (y < x.length());
```